# Inquery about validation in Django

Tags: django, django-validation

I have two questions.

1) can data be submitted in database without validation.If yes then how ?????

2) Can we use javascript in django for validation and if yes then how we post the data in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) use models with all fileds as balnk=True and null=True, and create a simple form without any validation methods.

2)Yes, you can use javascript/jquery to validate your forms and it has nothing to do with django. you can submit the form by two methods,

a) Normal form post

b) Ajax post,

```
$.post("url",$(formid).serialize());
```

Comment: OK, IF I am not using **if check_form.is_valid():** and submitting the data as **billing_add=check_form.cleaned_data['billing_add']** then there is a error that form doesnot have cleaned_data attribute which is right but if i am submitting without **cleaned_data** then there is a error of **Data truncated for column 'billing_add' at row 1** why ??

Comment: dats becuause your column length is too small to store entire data. Increase your column length in DB and model